# Incorrect width of UITableView from storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, storyboard

I am now developing an application using storyboard. I configure a view controller as below:

[image]

As you can see, I try to make a table view have a width around 100px. But the below image is the result:

[image]

I don't know why storyboard help me to resize the table view to around 320px.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!!!

Comment: With iOs simulator try to toggle Debug - Color Blended Layers, in the code check you do not set the table frame, check the resizing mask.

Comment: Thanks A-Live. I solved it by setting the autosizing mask